# How to optimize JOIN ON LIKE '%' + name + '%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.TestTable TT
  JOIN dbo.fnListParseAndSplit('test,tt,zz,er,ts',',') L ON TT.Name like '%' + L.ListMember + '%'
```

My issue is that on the execution plan I always get Index Seek for both cases when joining on:

1. T.Name like '%' + L.ListMember + '%'
2. T.Name like L.ListMember + '%'.

I was of the opinion that they are completely different and when the join is like '%' + L.ListMember + '%' I should get an index scan. 
Do I get something wrong on the execution plan? Or the SQL server 2008 is so smart that it can optimize my query?

I attached the execution plan. Do you know why do I have an index seek on the TestTabe Name column? The name column have an unique index ... but in this case I would expect a scan instead of seek.

http://softrun.ro/executionplan.png

Comment: apologies, I misunderstood what you were asking before the edit.

Comment: No problem ... I am not very good at SQL and it is hard for me to explain the problem.

Comment: What is the query plan please? XML or graphical?

Comment: I see it graphical ... but the main difference I was expecting is a index scan in first case and an index seek in the second case. But in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 I get index seek in both cases.

Comment: is the seek on the index for T.Name or L.Listmember - because it WILL seek on the listmember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index seek is related first part of join, if you look at the posted plan, you'll see table scan for output of your parse function.

Comment: But the index seek is the one that is selected and the one that do the join on LIKE '%' + L.ListMember + '%'. How can be there an index seek?

Comment: Because inner join involves 2 tables (relations) and records in both need to be processed. While determining the best execution plan, query optimizer examines output from your fnListParseAndSplit() function and decides to use TableScan as a best method to access the records returned. Then it looks at the other part of the join (TestTable) and discovers index IX_TestTable on column involved in join. So the best plan is : TableScan on function, IndexSeek on TestTable.